# Yarn: "Incorrect peer dependency" Me:?

Tags: angular, dependencies, yarnpkg

I have an angular project, managed by the yarn PM:

```
>ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.0.3
Node: 10.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.3
@angular/cdk                      6.4.7
@angular/cli                      7.0.3
@angular/material                 6.4.7
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
@schematics/angular               7.0.3
@schematics/update                0.10.3
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.4
webpack                           4.9.2
```

What should I do, if yarn informs me about the incorrect peer dependency?!
I know that that will not stop my (angular) project to be built, but I don't like warnings in my solution... What should I do to fix it?

```
C:\myproject>yarn upgrade
yarn upgrade v1.9.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/1040(node:22268) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @angular/cdk@6.4.7" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0".
warning " > @angular/cdk@6.4.7" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0".
warning " > @angular/material@6.4.7" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0".
warning " > @angular/material@6.4.7" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0".
warning " > angular2-csv@0.2.9" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0".
warning " > angular2-csv@0.2.9" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0".
warning "@angular-devkit/build-angular > @ngtools/webpack@6.1.5" has incorrect peer dependency "typescript@~2.4.0 || ~2.5.0 || ~2.6.0 || ~2.7.0 || ~2.8.0 || ~2.9.0".
warning " > codelyzer@4.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0".
warning " > codelyzer@4.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0".
warning " > codelyzer@4.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0".
warning " > codelyzer@4.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/platform-browser@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0".
warning " > codelyzer@4.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0".
...
```

my package.json file is bellow

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.1",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.9",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the version of your `@angular/core` ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun updated the OP

Answer (score 1):

The `angular5-csv` library has not been update for 7 months ([npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-csv)), if you want to get rid of the warnings you should remove the `angular5-csv` from your dependencies and use a more updated library or implement differently without it.

Comment: thanks. the question is not so much about angular5-csv, but rather what to do when "incorrect peer dependency" warning apprears

Comment: I updated my OP to reflect also the Angular version and recent messages after the Angular7/Node10 installation

Comment: In the libraries `package.json` there is a version spec for compatibility. You will keep the warning unless you take care of having compatible versions of libraries. If you want just to hide warnings you can use the `--silent` option.

Comment: and where I can find the "compatible versions of libraries" to update accordignly my package.json file?

Comment: Can you share you `package.json` ?

Comment: Some of the packages of the `@angular` scope are on version 6.* others on 7.*, try to run an `ng update` to have a status of what should be updated.

Comment: yarn upgrade is not sufficient?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182860/discussion-between-serge-and-ibenjelloun).